# Why doesn't my if/elsif statement create tagged links and send them to different routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, helper

My `if`/`elsif` statement is only executing the `if`, but not the `elsif`. I cannot understand why it is doing that. Sorry for not explaining how this works at all. The below edit explains it.

It is taking a string of text(a users post) and checking if it has a tag in it. If text has a tag then it will turn it into a link. The end result is the users string with the tags turned to links. The REGEX are the regular expressions to see if it has one of these tags `@`, `#`, `$`. They are not relevant as I know they are correct. For sample input it would be any type of post from twitter `@user is #cool`

```
REGEXS = [Supertag::Tag::USERTAG_REGEX, Supertag::Tag::HASHTAG_REGEX, Supertag::Tag::MONEYTAG_REGEX]

def linkify_tags(taggable_content)
  text = taggable_content.to_s

  REGEXS.each do
    if text = text.gsub(Supertag::Tag::USERTAG_REGEX) {link_to($&, usertag_path($2), class: 'tag')}
    elsif text = text.gsub(Supertag::Tag::HASHTAG_REGEX) {link_to($&, hashtag_path($2), class: 'tag')}
    elsif text = text.gsub(Supertag::Tag::MONEYTAG_REGEX) {link_to($&, moneytag_path($2), class: 'tag')}
    end  
  end     

  text.html_safe
end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or explanations of why it doesn't work? It only is executing the first of the `if/elsif`

Comment: We don't know what your previous question was. Is it significant to this question? If so, you need to add a link to it, otherwise, it's not necessary to even mention it.

Comment: no it's not really relevant. sorry about mentioning it.

Comment: edited that part out with a new explanation. Thanks!

Comment: As you're putting together a question, think about what you'd need to know in order to answer it, and put only that into it. Be concise, accurate, and you'll do well.

Comment: oh ok I didn't realize I needed to put the if/elsif into code format. sorry about that and thank you

Comment: It's a readability/comprehension thing. Stack Overflow, and the other Stack Exchange sites, have a goal of becoming like an online encyclopedia for their particular interest groups. And, so, like we'd see in books, we format some of the things we write. "if" is `if` when we're discussing the reserved word, just like `else`, or variables, methods, etc.

Comment: nope and I tried it just in case, but it didn't work. It seems to turn it into an uninitialized constant for my class. It is a helperclass for my Tag controller model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use if/else statements, you want to ask a question and perform one or the other based on the answer. It's called a conditional statement because you want a condition to be met before providing an action. Only after the answer is given you tell what to do next.

Now, what you are doing is the opposite. You tell what to do, without ever asking the question when to do it. No wonder it only runs the if statement, since this statement always returns true. The problem you face is that your first condition can never be false or nil.

As a rule of thumb, a question/condition should always have multiple possible answers, otherwise there is no point in asking.

Comment: ok so I should use a `case/when` statement? It works but the other cases execute only when the first is executed. I created a new question for it.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200048/case-when-statement-works-some-of-the-time)

Comment: Code within a when clause executes when the expression specified in the case matches that of the when. You are doing it wrong, because you are already performing an action instead of comparing expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your help I've learned a lot in researching this further.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
if foo = any_value_other_than_false_or_nil
  # this will always run
else …
  # this will never run
end
```

This is because you are assigning the value to the variable `foo`, and the result is 'truthy' (unless the value you assign is `nil` or `false`).

I think perhaps you meant to use `regex == …` to test if the regex variable matches a constant, or perhaps `regex =~ …` to test if the regex variable finds a match within a string. Similarly, perhaps you mean `text == …` instead of `text =`, to compare if they are equal instead of changing the value of the variable.

> *The first one tells me there's an unexpected "{"*

This is because Ruby (and I) have no idea what you mean by:

```
if foo = SomeConstant { some_code }
```

Perhaps if you ask another question describing your intention—and not just your code—others can help you achieve your end goal instead of answering questions about the symptoms.

Comment: By `regex ==` do you really mean `regex ===`?

Comment: @mu No, bc it appears that perhaps the OP is iterating an array of constants that are regexes, and checking to see which it is equal to.

Comment: That makes sense, I was missing the context.

Comment: @TaylorMitchell See the second half of my answer. What do you expect `SomeConstant { some_code }` to do?

Comment: actually it executes that code if the statement is true. I have used it before that way. so that code is supposed to check if the regex equals the hashtag, moneytag, or usertag and then execute using the '{link_to($&, usertag_path($2), class: 'tag')}'

Comment: edited my answer because I don't want to use the first method. The second one works I just have to figure out how to make the `elsif`s work. They aren't working even with an `==` and if I use `=~` it tells me there is no string

Comment: text == won't execute any of the code to make them links. === doesn't work either.

Comment: Last time: **what are you trying to do?** Yes, you're using the block form of gsub. What is sample input? What are the regex? What do you want to happen? What are you trying to test for in the `if` statements?

Comment: It is taking a string of text(a users post) and checking if it has a tag in it. If text has a tag then it will turn it into a link. The end result is the users string with the tags turned to links. The REGEX are the regular expressions to see if it has one of these tags `@`, `#`, `$`. They are not relevant as I know they are correct. For sample input it would be any type of post from twitter `@user is #cool`