# `Case/when` statement works some of the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok I am creating a gem that is supposed to find tags `#`, `@`, or `$` in user's posts. I am using a case when statement and it seems to work, only sometimes. For example I will have a string like `@you` and that works, but `#cool` does not work unless I add `#cool @you`. It seems the other `when` statements only work if the first `when` statement is true. The REGEX is just so it knows what to look for and I know those do work.

```
  REGEXS = [Supertag::Tag::USERTAG_REGEX, Supertag::Tag::HASHTAG_REGEX, Supertag::Tag::MONEYTAG_REGEX]

  def linkify_tags(taggable_content)
    text = taggable_content.to_s

    REGEXS.each do
      case text
      when text = text.gsub(Supertag::Tag::USERTAG_REGEX) {link_to($&, usertag_path($2), class: 'tag')}
      when text = text.gsub(Supertag::Tag::HASHTAG_REGEX) {link_to($&, hashtag_path($2), class: 'tag')}
      when text = text.gsub(Supertag::Tag::MONEYTAG_REGEX) {link_to($&, moneytag_path($2), class: 'tag')}
      end  
    end     

    text.html_safe
  end
```

Comment: honestly not sure why this is getting downvoted so much...

Comment: I don't understand why it is either. Isn't the point of this website to help people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason you iterate over `REGEXS`, ignore the item in the iteration, then hard-code them again... you actually do `text.gsub(Supertag::Tag::USERTAG_REGEX) ...` 3 times - once for each REGEX in your list.

Also, you misuse the `case when` construct, I suggest you read [more about it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm)

You should either drop the `each` entirely, and use only the explicit constants, or refactor you code to work dynamically, maybe something like:

```
  REGEXS = [[Supertag::Tag::USERTAG_REGEX, :usertag_path], 
            [Supertag::Tag::HASHTAG_REGEX, :hashtag_path], 
            [Supertag::Tag::MONEYTAG_REGEX, :moneytag_path]]

  def linkify_tags(taggable_content)
    text = taggable_content.to_s

    REGEXS.each do |regex, path|
      text = text.gsub(regex) {link_to($&, send(path, $2), class: 'tag')}
    end     

    text.html_safe
  end
```

Comment: worked perfectly. I really need to brush up on how i understand these and the `if/elsif` statements